# Passing model data in an Html Content return from the controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I recently received a request from a client to create a method that would allow them to directly email a user from an admin account from the contents of a completed form.

```
Controller:
[HttpGet]
     public ActionResult ThisView() {
         thisModel model = new thisModel();
    emailAddress = model.EmailAddress

         return Content('<a href="mailto:"model.emailAddress"', "text/html")
        }
View:

 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2  raw-value"><span class="WebsiteContent"  data-ControlID="divPOC_Email" data-Component="11"></span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "sample@email.com", maxlength = 100 })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 field-validation-error userErrorMessage hidden" data-valmsg="user">Required</div>
        </div>
```

The data is being retrieved from a user input, and returned to an administrator view of the completed form. The request is to pass the email address as a clickable link that will allow them to email the user directly from the form. Is it possible to pass the model data directly into the view as a raw HTML String containing the existing data?

Comment: `"<a href=\"mailto:" + model.EmailAddress + "\">`?

Comment: @CodeCaster I will give that a try

Comment: Can someone please tell me why this is downvoted?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain step by step what you want to happen. Don't just show a non-compiling snippet that doesn't do what you want, explain the entire scenario. The user enters their email address in a textbox, and then what?

Comment: Most likely because your question is not clear. It also seems like this is an XY problem, where you're asking about how to fix the solution you landed on rather than about the actual problem you truly need to solve.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, i will edit this to better reflect the issue I am trying to solve. I appreciate the feedback

Comment: @CodeCaster Updated edit, to clarify the process and issue that I need resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question extremely unclear. It looks like you *might* be using a child action here, but even that doesn't really make sense.

If you want to display the *value on your model* as a link, you need only use `Html.DisplayFor`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
```

The default display template for an email address is to wrap it in a link. This assumes, of course that you're decorated your `EmailAddress` property with `[EmailAddress]` and/or `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]`.

Comment: I have edited the question, to reflect the issue. The objective is to return the existing email address input by the user to an administrator account that will then be able to email the user directly from that location in the form.